# Force the order of a stacked barplot in ggplot when the bars come from diff columns, and labels come from diff columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have this sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2022-11-15 04:06:30", "2022-11-16 04:06:43", "2022-11-17 06:27:57", "2022-11-17 11:07:18")),
  serial_number = c("2097210", "2097203", "2106093", "2097208"),
  sensor_1 = c(0.03, 0.050288, 0.131424, 0.050692),
  sensor_2 = c(0.02, 0.04463, 0.018534, 0.038841),
  sensor_3 = c(0.024268, 0.039078, 0.011794, 0.020183),
  sensor_4 = c(0.011116, 0.024343, 0.009267, 0.016428),
  sensor_5 = c(0.004697, 0.017083, 0.009267, 0.007393),
  error_codes1 = c("F4", "F3","F2","F4"),
  error_codes2 = c("F4", "F3","F2","F4"),
  error_codes3 = c("F2", "F1","F3","F8"),
  error_codes4 = c("F4", "F7","F3","F1"),
  error_codes5 = c("F2", "F6","F1","F4")
)
```

What I is create a stacked bar chart, where serial_number is the x-axis, and the y-axis is based on the sensor columns. The first row of bars on the bottom should be all the values in sensor_1. These should be colored by the error_codes in the legend. Then i want to stack ABOVE THE SENSOR_1 BARS, THE SENSOR_2 BARS. The order is very important. and so on. However, nothing I do can easily create the desired plot. Here is my best attempt:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=serial_number)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sensor_1, fill=error_codes1), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sensor_2, fill=error_codes2), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sensor_3, fill=error_codes3), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sensor_4, fill=error_codes4), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sensor_5, fill=error_codes5), position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

Nothing I do forces the order of the bars to remain in the specific order I add the columsn to the bar plot. sensor_should ALWAYS be on the bottom and sensor_5 should ALWAYS be last. Please help

Comment: ggplot likes a long data, convert your data wide-to-long to avoid repetition in your ggplot codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating user zx8754's comment into code, reshaping your data is key. The tidyverse comes with some handy functions for data reshaping.

Additionally, for a "stacked bar chart" from top to bottom, I guess you want to simply switch x and y aesthetic.

Also, `geom_bar` has `position_stack` as default, thus no need to specify. and geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") would therefore be equivalent to simply `geom_col`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(serial_number, datetime),
    names_to = c(".value", "serial_no"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)([1-9])"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = serial_no, x = sensor_, fill = error_codes)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I read this more as wanting one column for each serial number. Again, reshaping your data is the key. Just to make it clear what this means, let us pivot and summarize your data into something more suitable for plotting:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_df <- df %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("error_codes", "error_", .x)) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("sensor", "reading", .x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:12, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "sensor")) %>%
  group_by(serial_number, error) %>%
  summarise(reading = sum(reading))

plot_df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   serial_number [4]
#>    serial_number error reading
#>    <chr>         <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 2097203       F1    0.0391 
#>  2 2097203       F3    0.0949 
#>  3 2097203       F6    0.0171 
#>  4 2097203       F7    0.0243 
#>  5 2097208       F1    0.0164 
#>  6 2097208       F4    0.0969 
#>  7 2097208       F8    0.0202 
#>  8 2097210       F2    0.0290 
#>  9 2097210       F4    0.0611 
#> 10 2106093       F1    0.00927
#> 11 2106093       F2    0.150  
#> 12 2106093       F3    0.0211
```

Now we can plot much more easily:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(serial_number, reading, fill = error)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), col = "gray50") +
  scale_fill_brewer("Error\nCode", palette = "Set3") +
  xlab("Serial #") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: probably more what the OP wanted. , not sure though :)